# EXC_BAD_ACCESS writing char to txt file

Tags: c, exc-bad-access, text-files

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])

{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("/Users/--------/Desktop/C.txt", "w");
    putc("C", "/Users/-------/Desktop/C.txt");
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Here is my simple code for writing the letter "C" into the textfile C.txt. I get the error code EXC_BAD_ACCESS every time I write it. Whats happeneing?

Comment: You must have got several warnings when you compile your code. They are for a reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how `putc` should be used. Try:

```
putc('C', fp);
```

`putc` looks like this:

```
int putc(int c, FILE *stream);
```

You are passing a `char *` instead of a `FILE *`.

Comment: Also, `putc()` takes a character as parameter, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
 putc('C', fp);
```

putc expects its second parameter to be `FILE*`, not a path to the file.

First parameter should also be char, not char* as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You should write to the file:

```
putc('C', fp);
```

Also, you should check that `fopen` didn't return `NULL`